# Calendars created with service account cannot add atendee

Tags: google-calendar-api

I've created 2 calendars using service accounts (tried both with a service account key locally and with the default service account running in Firebase Functions).

When I try to add an event in one calendar and invite the other calendar I get a 403 from the calendar API:
**'Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority.'**

I have calendars created like this aprox. 6 months ago and they can add atendees, what am I doing wrong?

PS: I don't have any "real" user emails involved, I just want to control the calendars created on the service account user. Also, no G Suite domain, it's just a Firebase app.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority.

Means exactly that in order for a service account to invite attendees to an event the service account must have be authorized to the domain using Domain wide delegation.

Yes this means you need to have a gsuite account.  It does not work with standard accounts.  You will need to use Oauth2 if you dont have a gsuite account.

Comment: Thank you! Can you point me to some link around setting Oauth for server-to-server auth ? 

The thing that is confusing me is that this is server-to-server flow, I mean I test locally with a service account key but in production it is a firebase function interacting with the calendar (creating them and adding events).